# What version of PySVN to install? "client is too old to work with the working copy"

Tags: python, pysvn

My SVN repository is installed on Linux CentOS at http://myserver.com/svnrepo, and `svn --version` on the server gives 1.7.4.

On my local PC I have Windows 7, Python 2.7 (and latest Tortoise SVN).

I just installed PySVN from http://pysvn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=1768. I was unsure which version to install, I choose `PySVN 1.7.7 for python 2.7 and svn 1.7.8`.

I tried short script, but I get error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    WDIR= "D:/SVN/Project/trunk"
    client = pysvn.Client()
    entry = client.info2(WDIR)
    print entry
```

Error reported is:
`This client is too old to work with the working copy at
'D:\SVN\Project\trunk' (format 31).
You need to get a newer Subversion client.`

If I try to ping remote SVN folder - it works:

`REPOURL = "https://www.myserver.com/svnrepo/projects/Project/trunk"
 client = pysvn.Client()
 entry = client.info2(REPOURL)`

**How do I check which version of svn client does PySVN use?

How do I check which versin is my working copy?

What version of PySVN do I need to install?**

Comment: Always install the newest version of any software, unless you have specific reasons to use an older version

Comment: Sooo many versions of PySVN are offered on that link that I thought it really matters which one to choose?!

Comment: Of course it matters what you choose. Different versions offer different functionality

Comment: Anyway, I'd like to know what's going on with those versions if possible.

Comment: What do you want to know? It doesn't work because it's too old of a version, use a newer version

Comment: Based on the info I provided, what version of PySVN do I need to install?

Comment: I don't know anything about pysvn. Best bet is to try the newest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Subversion working copy format changed in Subversion 1.8. Since you are using the latest TortoiseSVN, your working copies must be in this format. To access the working copies that were created or updated by TortoiseSVN, you'll need a version of PySVN (and any other client you use) that is based on Subversion 1.8 or 1.9.

Comment: Thanks. I installed `PySVN 1.7.9 for python 2.7 and svn 1.8.5` which seems to be the latest one. It works!

Comment: ...and Tortoise SVN web page says: `The current version 1.9.1 is linked against the Subversion library 1.9.1.` This is the critical peace of info I was looking for.